# Information theoretic alternative to hypergeometric test

Tags: aic, information-theory, fishers-exact-test, hypergeometric-distribution

Is there any information-theoretic alternative to the hypergeometric test (or Fisher's exact test)? In other word, is it possible to calculate AIC values for data which one would classically analyse with these tests?

Comment: Well, you'd calculate a change in AIC between the null model and the alternative model... but it wouldn't be a hypothesis test; you could look on it as model selection though.

Comment: That is fine, and the fact that this is not a hypothesis test is actually what I want. All I need is to calculate the respective likelihoods for H0 and H1.

Comment: Likelihoods for contingency tables are critical to the [G test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-test), so the calculation of the likelihoods of such tables is done. Exactly which likelihood you get depends on the assumptions you make. If you condition on both margins as with the Fisher test, clearly the likelihood is hypergeometric for the null, but the G-test already deals with the log of the likelihood ratio. You might find [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-test#Relation_to_Kullback-Leibler_divergence) a useful starting point.

Comment: See also p859 [here](http://nitro.biosci.arizona.edu/courses/EEB519A-2007/pdfs/MLE.pdf). I'll try to come back and write up an answer. Note that if something computes the LR test you just need to adjust that statistic to get the difference in AIC

Comment: @Glen_b would you mind rephrasing your comments as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [G-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-test) for the 2x2 table, which is a likelihood ratio test, is of the form

$$ G = 2\sum_{i} {O_{i} \cdot \ln(O_{i}/E_{i}) }\; .$$

This is $-2 \log \Lambda$ for the situation where you fix the overall total and work with multinomials. (It may also be the LR test for the situation where you fix one margin and deal with binomials, but I haven't double checked that.)

So it's possible to compute an AIC for the difference between the two; you could simply add twice the difference in parameters to $-2 \log \Lambda$. Or the likelihood of the individual models could be written out for the fixed overall total case.